# Neo4j search unknown number of properties

Tags: list, neo4j, cypher

I've got graph like that:

(A)-[r1]-(B)-[r2]-(C)

The thing is, that r1 and r2 can have different number of properties.

```
relation1:
   index1: 10
   index2: 2

relation2:
   index1: 6
   index2: 4
   index3: 5
```

Is it possible to search among all properties without knowing their names? Or is there better way to keep lists in neo4j?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to do this in "native" cypher, but you could use [automatic relationship indexing](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/auto-indexing.html) that uses Lucene. I think you can do the following in Cypher:

```
START r=rel:rel_auto_index("*:'your_search_value'")
RETURN startNode(r), endNode(r), type(r);
```

Make sure automatic indexing is enabled in your Neo4j properties:

```
relationship_auto_indexing = true
```

Comment: Isn't it going to slow drastically insertion of relations?

Comment: It's going to have an impact for sure. You'll have to decide what's more important to you, insertion or search performance.

Comment: Well, definitely insertion is more important since this db grows continuously. Is there any way to run indexing on existing nodes e.g. once a day or week?

Comment: You don't have to use automatic indexing. Instead you could run a script at a fixed amount of time that updates the indexes accordingly. You can't do this with cypher though. You'll need to do this programmatically with e.g. Java.

Answer (score 2):

Property values can be lists, as long as all the elements are the same type. So you can have

```
match (A) -[r1]-> (B) -[r2]-> (C) set r1.vals = [10, 6], r2.vals=[6, 4, 5]
```

and later search with

```
match (A) -[r]-> (B) where 10 in r.vals return a,b
```

I don't know whether this works with indexing, so presumably tstorms' answer is better if you have a lot of these relationships.